# Ubuntu 19 Screen Flickering

Tags: graphics, power-management, intel

Just installed Ubuntu 19 (Dual Boots with my windows 10)...on my laptop (HP Spectre X360) and the screen has been flickering whether on battery power or on power supply (tried changing the refresh rate to a lowest rate available BUT it didn't work).
With my windows 10 installation i used to experience the same but i went to my Intel Graphic controls and changed the power settings and disabled the panel self refresh and display power saving technology and this worked ...

am not sure whether this is what i need to do with my Ubuntu 19 and if so does anyone know how to go about this ?

Comment: +1.  
Weirdly enough, my issue only appears when the second monitor is in the portrait mode.  Landscape mode works fine.  Graphics = intel uhd 620